# How to avoid aggregation of measure values in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to retrieve and analyze records from SQL server. Whenever I drag the measure values to rows field it gets auto aggregating itself in tableau.

I dont want this aggregation to be done since my values doesn't make sense when it gets agregated.

[image]

Is there a solution to remove this aggregation in tableau ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid aggregating values. However, your problem isn't that you are aggregating your values, your problem is that you are treating dimensions as measures.

To fix this you can convert `Year` from a measure to a dimension:

[image]

Of course, if you want to disaggregate the measures then you can always do that too:

[image]